# how to avoid AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I had an existing class like this - a.b.c.Message.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Message", indexes = { @Index(name = "messageIdIndex", columnList = "messageId"),
        @Index(name = "customerIndex", columnList = "customer")})
        public class Message extends BaseEntity {
    ///other fields and columns...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "msg",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Application1> app1;
    
    /// *newly added 
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "msg",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Application2> app2;


    /// setters and getters and toString() and equals() overridden
```

and second class: a.b.c.Application1.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Application1", indexes = { @Index(name = "applicationIdIndex", columnList = "app1Id"),
        @Index(name = "customerIndex", columnList = "customer")})
public class Application1 extends BaseEntity {
    /// other fields and columns
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH }, optional = true)
    private Message msg;
    ///setter and getters and other methods
}
```

this works fine, however when I add another class - a.b.c.d.Application2.java:(* and the second field app2 in Message class is added )-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Application2", indexes = { @Index(name = "application2IdIndex", columnList = "app2Id"),
        @Index(name = "customerIndex", columnList = "customer")})
public class Application2 extends BaseEntity {
    /// other fields and columns
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH }, optional = true)
    private Message msg;
    ///setter and getters and other methods
}
```

now, when I try to create the EntityManagerFactory I get an exception like this -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: a.b.c.Message.app2[a.b.c.d.Application2]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1196)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

here's what I tried

1. read in some answers to a similar issue to check if the Entity annotation is from javax.persistence package instead of the hibernate package
2. missing Entity annotation - not the case
3. i have some doubts that this could be beacuse my new class in inside a sub package ,but the exception was there even after moving the class to the base package (a.b.c)

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue, the new class had to be added in the persistence.xml, didn't face this issue as other newly added entity are using spring data jpa, while the older entities are using hibernate (currently transitioning from hibernate to jpa) , however one of the newly added entity was being used in the older classes which relied on the xml for finding entities.